# initialize the instance variable with a constructor

Tags: variables, constructor, initialization, instance

As far as I'm now I have this:

> class Vehicle{
>
> int registrationNumber;

Now I need to make a constructor for the registrationNumber.
How do I do this?
(I've seen some with the this.=
what does the this. do?

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework? What language is this, what have your tried?

Answer (score 0):

**this** keyword returns the reference to the current object.

```
class Vehicle{

    int registrationNumber;

    Vehicle(int registrationNumber){
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

}
```